# Symfony2 Form handleRequest fails to bind the POST data of a foreign field to the entity

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

First off, here's my DB design.

Each Story is related to a single Project.

```
-----------     --------------
| project |     | story      |
-----------     --------------
| id      |     | id         |
| name    |     | project_id |
-----------     | name       |
                --------------
```

The relationship between **Project** and **Story** is defined using the following code.

**Entity/Project.php**

```
class Project {
     ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Story", mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $stories;
    ...
}
```

**Entity/Story.php**

```
class Story {
    ...
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="stories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    private $project;
    ...
}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/story/create/project/{id}", name="storyCreate")
 */
public function createAction($id, Request $request) {

    /* Get project by id */
    $project = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Project')
        ->find($id);

    /* Create new story instance and set project */
    $story = new Story();
    $story->setProject($project);

    /* Generate the form and handle the request */
    $form = $this->createForm(CreateStoryType::class, $story);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    /* Form is submitted and valid */
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /* Create the objects */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($story);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $this->context['form'] = $form->createView();

    return $this->render('project/create.html.twig', $this->context);
}
```

I also followed this guide to create a Project to ID transformer.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#about-model-and-view-transformers

Now on initial loading of page everything looks perfect.
I'm presented with a form with a `Project` and `Title` input textboxes with the `Project` field pre-populated with the current project indicated in the URL.

Upon submitting however, the `Project` field always gets the `This value should not be blank.` validation error even if it's not empty. Am I doing it right? I can't even access `$story->getProject()` anymore as it gets set to `null` after submission.

Comment: You might also want to include your `CreateStoryType` and the DataTransformer.

Comment: @jbafford, you know what, thank you for asking for my **DataTransformer** code. I was about to post it when I noticed my `reverseTransform` method wasn't returning the entity at all. Damn been pulling my hair for days because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok because of @jbafford's comment I found the problem.

My Data transformer wasn't returning the entity in the `reverseTransform` method.